# How to use iOS 5 built-in dictionary with programmable?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

[This app](http://itunes.apple.com/app/id473493861) is using iOS 5's built-in dictionary with UISearchBar.

I want to include this feature for my iOS app.

But, I Can't find document in developer.apple.

If you tell me about it and example code, Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly there isn't an api for the built-in dictionary. The only thing you can use in that direction is the [UITextChecker class](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextChecker_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It seems to me, that the app you are talking about uses it too.

Comment: oh, I got to understand. thank you yinkou.